# Line mode command to delete from column X to end of line?

Tags: command-line, gvim

Using gvim on a file with 30K lines, I want to use ex mode to delete from column 130 to end of line, making each record no longer than 130 characters.
I want to do this for the entire file.

My macro to do this is `131|D`. How can I do this from the colon prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\%c` to match a column in a substitution:

```
:%s/\%131c.*//
```

For more help see:

```
:h /\%c
```